# gcp: events are not consistent for resource type. "operation" is missing for buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket, google-cloud-logging

According to following [GCP link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)
standards event structure in json should have operation details. But found that for storage bucket operation entry is missing in log to identify it as last action occurred.

```
"operation": {
    object (LogEntryOperation)
  }
```

Other resource.type = firewall rule

```
"operation": {
    "id": "operation-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "producer": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  }
```

How to get operation details as mandatory object to be received in events?
If GCP doesn't support `operation:{}` in events consistently any evidence would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`"last"` is an optional field and may not be populated. This cannot be enforced.
You can try enabling [bucket logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging) to gather more information about events regarding your storage or create a Feature Request at [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to have this option added in future.